# Личный кабинет пользователя

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы при входе на сайт (логин, пароль) пользователь входил в СВОЙ личный кабинет, т.е. видел только свои сообщения и т.д. Как вывести запрос к базе, я понимаю, а вот как сделать так, чтобы не вводить логин пароль на каждой странице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте по **session_start()** и **$_SESSION**

```
Страница авторизации:

    <?php
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['user'] = "Irina";
      echo 'Вы вошли как: '.$_SESSION['user'];
    ?>

Личный кабинет:

<?
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['user'].', добро пожаловать в Личный Кабинет';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сессии, читай, изучай, используй

- http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php
- http://text.md/session/

Answer (score 1):

После успешной авторизации, записать данные пользователя в куки или сессии.

Проверять наличие таких данных в куках и сессиях, если есть, проверять по БД на верность этих данных, затем позволить работать дальше.

Answer (score -1):

Ну для того чтобы не выводить что-либо на каждой странице - надо перенести повторяющийся фрагмент в подключаемый файл. Ну и соответственно подключать его используя include.

Answer (score -1):

Скоро на хэшкоде будут спрашивать - "как постирать пуховик".
Вот пример регистрации, используется БД и сессии, в теме есть примеры используя файлы и БД для записи пользователей и паролей.

[Пример авторизации/регистрации/выхода (на файлах и БД)](http://www.php.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14334)